# Postgres database backup not working locally (Crontab + Shell script using expect)

Tags: shell, cron, backup, psql, expect

I am having issues on my Ubuntu server: I have two scripts which perform a pg_dump of two databases (a remote and a local one). However the backup file for the local one always ends up empty.

When I run the script manually, no problem.
The issue is when the script is ran via crontab while I am NOT logged into the machine. If I'm in a SSH session no problem, it works with crontab but when I'm not connected it does not work.

Check out my full scripts/setup under, and feel free to suggest any improvements. For now I just want it to work but if my method is insecure/unefficient I would gladly hear about alternatives :)

So far I've tried:

- Using the postgres user for the local database (instead of another user I use to access the DB with my applications)
- Switch `pg_dump` for `/usr/bin/pg_dump`

Here's my setup:

- Crontab entry:

`0 2 * * * path/to/my/script/local_databasesBackup.sh ; path/to/my/script/remote_databasesBackup.sh`

- scriptInitialization.sh

```
set LOCAL_PWD "password_goes_here"
set REMOTE_PWD "password_goes_here"
```

- Expect script, called by crontab (local/remote_databaseBackup.sh):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

source path/to/my/script/scriptInitialization.sh

spawn path/to/my/script/localBackup.sh expect "Password: " send "${LOCAL_PWD}\r"

expect eof exit
```

- Actual backup script (local/remoteBackup.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")

delete_yesterday_backup_and_perform_backup () {
    /usr/bin/pg_dump -U postgres -W -F t localDatabaseName > /path/to/local/backup/folder/$DATE.tar

    YESTERDAY_2_AM=$(date  --date="02:00 yesterday" +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
    YESTERDAY_BACKUP_FILE=/path/to/local/backup/folder/$YESTERDAY_2_AM.tar

    if [ -f "$YESTERDAY_BACKUP_FILE" ]; then
        echo "$YESTERDAY_BACKUP_FILE exists. Deleting"
        rm $YESTERDAY_BACKUP_FILE
    else 
        echo "$YESTERDAY_BACKUP_FILE does not exist."
    fi
}

CURRENT_DAY_NUMBER=$(date +"%d")
FIRST_DAY_OF_THE_MONTH="01"

if [ "$CURRENT_DAY_NUMBER" = "$FIRST_DAY_OF_THE_MONTH" ]; then 
    echo "First day of the month: Backup without deleting the previous backup"
    /usr/bin/pg_dump -U postgres -W -F t localDatabaseName > /path/to/local/backup/folder/$DATE.tar
else 
    echo "Not the first day of the month: Delete backup from yesterday and backup"
    delete_yesterday_backup_and_perform_backup
fi
```

The only difference between my local and remote script is the pg_dump parameters:

- Local looks like this `/usr/bin/pg_dump -U postgres -W -F t localDatabaseName > /path/to/local/backup/folder/$DATE.tar`
- Remote looks like this: `pg_dump -U remote_account -p 5432 -h remote.address.com -W -F t remoteDatabase > /path/to/local/backup/folder/$DATE.tar`

I ended up making two scripts because I thought it may have been the cause of the issue. However I'm pretty sure it's not at the moment.